# Using 6 columns of time series data, conduct pairwise analysis on all possible iterations (in R)

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataframe `mydf` containing 6 columns of time series data.

I want to calculate the correlation of all this data, which can easily be done through `cor(mydf)`. However, I want to multiply each of the correlations by the square root of the relevant long-run variances (I adopt an arbitrary autocorrelation lag of 5) of each pairwise column.

To demonstrate, `val = cor(mydf[,1], mydf[,2])`

```
cov_temp1 = acf(mydf[,1], type = "covariance", lag.max = 5, plot = FALSE, na.action = na.pass)$acf
cov_temp2 = acf(mydf[,2], type = "covariance", lag.max = 5, plot = FALSE, na.action = na.pass)$acf
s.e. = sqrt((cov_temp1[1]+2*sum(cov_temp1[-1]))/nrow(mydf) * (cov_temp2[1]+2*sum(cov_temp2[-1]))/nrow(mydf))
```

Then, the pairwise statistic for column 1 and 2 is `val*s.e.`. Assuming I have 6 columns of data, which I do, I want to construct the same statistic for all iterations of pairwise columns and then sum them up. I am not entirely sure how to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to CV and thank you for your great answer. Note that this site is about statistics and not about "R-Programming". Maybe you should edit your question to make clearer why your question focuses on statistics and not on programming.

Comment: Oops, perhaps you are right. I am trying to construct a diebold mariano statistic that takes into account both time-series and cross-sectional variations in loss differences. mydf contains 6 loss functions comparing two models across 6 stocks. I want to find the best model on average